# Sum of Dirac measures is not regular

Tags: measure-theory, lebesgue-measure, dirac-delta

Prove that:

$$\mu(A)=\sum_{n\in\mathbb{N}}\delta_{\frac{1}{n}}(A)$$

is not a regular measure.

A measure is regular if:

$$ \mu(A) = \inf \{ \mu (G)|A\subset G, G\text{ is open}\} = \sup \{ \mu (F)| F\subset A, F \text{ is closed} \}$$

for any measurable $A$.

I'm trying to find a counter example for that but can't come up with any.

I was thinking about a set which contains a finite number of 1/n but can only be covered by $(0,\epsilon)$ for some $\epsilon >0$, leading to a contradiction.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take $A=\{0\}\subseteq \Bbb R$. For every open set $G$ containing $A$ there exists an $\varepsilon>0$ such that $]-\varepsilon, \varepsilon[\subseteq G$. This open interval contains infinitely many $\frac 1 n$. Thus $\mu(G)\geq \mu(]-\varepsilon,\varepsilon[) = \infty$. But $\mu(A)=0$. This shows that $\mu$ is not outer regular.